# Using DataStore Preferences Kotlin Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm following [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#kts) documentation and attempting to implement DataStore preferences in my app, but I'm having trouble doing so.

I have the following code, and errors in three lines:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore
import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.stringPreferencesKey
import androidx.datastore.preferences.preferencesDataStore
import com.example.mymentalhealth.ui.theme.MyMentalHealthTheme
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import java.util.prefs.Preferences
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map

val Context.dataStore: DataStore<Preferences> by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings") // Error 1

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyAppTheme {
                val ACCOUNT_TYPE = stringPreferencesKey("account_type")
                val accountTypeFlow: Flow<String> = context.dataStore.data // Error 2
                    .map { preferences -> // Error 3
                        preferences[ACCOUNT_TYPE] ?: ""
                    }

                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Hello, World")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error 1: Property delegate must have a 'getValue(Context, KProperty*>)' method. None of the following functions are suitable.
getValue(Context, KProperty<*>) defined in kotlin.properties.ReadOnlyProperty

Error 2: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
context() defined in kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.CompletedContinuation
context() defined in kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.NoOpContinuation

Error 3: Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.

I'm following the documentation exactly except for using a string instead of an int. I'm also unsure how to access and use the variable (for example implementing it in an if statement). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Error 1: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of these errors seem to stem from bad import statements, it would have been helpful if you included those in your question as well.
The following tries to guess what probably went wrong.

Although I cannot reproduce your **Error 1**, errors of this kind can usually be fixed by adding `import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue`.

**Error 2** seems to come from importing `kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.NoOpContinuation.context` or something similar. What you want instead is to replace `context.dataStore.data` with `applicationContext.dataStore.data`.

**Error 3** will be solved by the quick fix offered to you after you've fixed the previous errors. You are probably just missing `import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map`.

---

In response to the edited question:

**Error 1** seems to originate from `import java.util.prefs.Preferences`. It should be `import androidx.datastore.preferences.core.Preferences` instead. This will also fix "*No value passed for parameter 'def'*".

Although I cannot reproduce the error "*Flow operator functions should not be invoked within composition*" (or is it a warning?) that really is a point of concern: Flow operators can, depending on the pressure of the flow and the operation to be performed, quite time consuming. That is incompatible with the requirement that composabe functions should only perform light calculations and terminate quickly. The common solution is to move the flow to a view model (the data store flow actually belongs even further down in the layer architecture, in the data layer. Also see https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture#data-layer).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll update the question with import statements. I still have the same problem with Error 1, and I came across two new errors: With `.map` I get the error "Flow operator functions should not be invoked within composition" and with `preferences[ACCOUNT_TYPE] ?: ""` I get the error "No value passed for parameter 'def'". I'm also still unsure as to how to access the variable. Edit: I also uploaded a screenshot of the error message I'm getting for Error 1.

Comment: Thank you for your revised response. The flow operator error was a warning I think and was fixed by moving the flow to the outside of the `setContent` and `Theme`. I one follow up question however: How can I access the variable from the flow?

Comment: Make sure it is a `StateFlow` in your view model by calling `stateIn()`. Then, in your compose code, you can retrieve the value with `val accountType by viewmodel.flow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()`. You need the artifact `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose` for that. If you need more help, please ask a separate question focused on that.