# Accessing DataStore flow variables kotlin jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to access Flow data in a component and I'm not sure how to do so. I have the following code here that defines a flow from a DataStore string:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val ACCOUNT_TYPE = stringPreferencesKey("account_type")
        val accountTypeFlow: Flow<String> = applicationContext.dataStore.data
            .map { preferences ->
                preferences[ACCOUNT_TYPE] ?: ""
            }
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyAppTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Text(text = "") // display flow value here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also unsure whether `preferences[ACCOUNT_TYPE] ?: ""` above is what I need or something else. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78063155/6216216), the flow doesn't belong in the composable. First thing would be to move it to the view model where you should make it to a `StateFlow` with:

```
.stateIn(
    scope = viewModelScope,
    started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
    initialValue = /* some initial value to use until the underlying flow produces its first value */,
)
```

(In clean architecture, the data store is part of the data layer, so the data store flow should be moved to a dedicated repository class. Only the `stateIn()` actually belongs in the view model and is applied to the flow that the view model retrieved from the repository.)

Now, let's assume in your activity the variable `viewModel` holds an instance of your view model, you can collect the flow inside a composable (f.e. as a first line in the `setContent` lambda) by calling:

```
val accountType by viewModel.accountTypeFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
```

This requires the artifact `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose` in your gradle dependencies. It is a lifecycle-aware collection of the flow tailored to the use in compose ([more details](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/consuming-flows-safely-in-jetpack-compose-cde014d0d5a3)). It returns a compose `State` object that is directly delegated to the `accountType` variable (note the delegation operator `by` instead of the assignment operator `=`), so that variable now holds the *content* of the state object. It is of the same type as the content of your flow, in your case a `String`.

This variable is always up-to-date with the current value of your flow. As soon as the value of the flow changes, this variable also changes its value.

Since all of this happens in a composable, a recomposition is triggered whenever a new value arrives, so everything that follows will get updated with the new value. As an example, this will always display the newest value that the flow produced:

```
Text(text = accountType)
```

Regarding your last question: `preferences[ACCOUNT_TYPE]` retrieves the current preference for `"account_type"`. This preference may very well be missing, as it will be for a freshly installed app. In that case `null` is returned. It's up to you what you want as a fallback. `?: ""` falls back to an empty string.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you go into a little more detail as to how to implement a view model and the StateFlow? Is a view model essentially a class? I found documentation of view models and state but I can't seem to apply it to what I'm doing.

Comment: That would, again, be another question. But it is pretty standard, there are already lots of questions about that, you probably should just take a alook at an example. It's not complicated. The [Sunflower example project](https://github.com/android/sunflower) is pretty simple and demonstrates how to use a layered architecture. Just check it out as a new project in Android Studio ("*Get from Version Control...*") and take a look around. It aso uses Hilt for Dependency Injection.

Comment: ... if you don't have Git installed you can download the project as a Zip file via the green button on the Website and import it into Android Studio.

Comment: thank you for your response. I'm not sure where to look for State Flow in a view model in that example. I did post another question found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78064026/accessing-datastore-flow-variables-kotlin-jetpack-compose

Comment: I guess you meant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78097879/view-models-for-flow-data-and-retrofit-http-requests

Comment: yes sorry about that, I'll update my comment.